# Losing session data in ASP.NET. Redirected to Login page

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-variables, session-cookies

my code was all okay before I added the following code. Now when I click on home after submitting a form, I am redirected to the login page.

I added the following two blocks of code  in different sections and both of them are timing out my session variable

**1st block:**

```
        DateTime date1 = DateTime.UtcNow;
        string dateTime = date1.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmm");
        string fileName = string.Concat(string.Concat(jRequestId, "-"), dateTime);
        string jsonLogFolderPath = "~/App_code/jsonLog";
        if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath(jsonLogFolderPath)))
        {
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath(jsonLogFolderPath));
        }
        string path = Server.MapPath(jsonLogFolderPath + "/" + fileName + ".txt");

        if (!File.Exists(path))
        {
            using (System.IO.StreamWriter jsonLogFile = new System.IO.StreamWriter(path))
            {
                jsonLogFile.Write(json);
                jsonLogFile.Close();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            divErrorMsg.Style.Add("display", "block");
            ErrorLog.LogError(new Exception("Unable to create Text file"));
            dbconn.Close();
            return;
        }
```

**2nd block:** `

```
            string requestID = Session["requestID"].ToString();

            string reportsFolderPath = "~/App_code/Reports";
            if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath(reportsFolderPath)))
            {
               System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath(reportsFolderPath));
            }
            string reportsPath = Server.MapPath(reportsFolderPath + "/" + "ReportSubmissionSummary-" + requestID + ".pdf");

            if (!File.Exists(reportsPath))
            {
               BinaryWriter reportWriter = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream(reportsPath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None));
              reportWriter.Write(bytes);
                reportWriter.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                divErrorMsg.Style.Add("display", "block");
                ErrorLog.LogError(new Exception("Unable to store the pdf Report"));
                dbconn.Close();
                return;
            }
```

Comment: So then removing the code fixes the issue?

Comment: I need to create the files so I cant remove the code.

Comment: Do you know what line you are sticking on?

Comment: streamwriter is giving me all the trouble

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing files in your app_code folder (or bin folder, web.config file , machine.config file) will cause the application to restart and will be the reason why you loose your session information - assuming that you are using the standard inproc session management.

If possible the simplest solution would be not to write In to that folder, if you absolutely have to, then you will have to move away from in memory session management to an alternative method

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. If you are happy with the answer, then mark it accepted. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers